# Adding Role to User on Register

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP .NET CORE 2 and i get stuck on one problem:
1) I created new asp core mvc project with Individual User Accounts.
2) I added custom roles to my app via [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51333.asp-net-core-2-0-getting-started-with-identity-and-role-management.aspx) tutorial 
Now I want to display all this role in some kid of html select in register view (/Account/Register) and when user will fill form, choose role from select and click "Register" button he will be added to DB with role assigned to him. 
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity pacakges. This package includes several classes to get roles and users. The main classes are RoleManager and UserManager. If you would like to get all the roles you can do

`var allRoles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();`

You should be able to go from there to get this in your model and get a select constructed.

Here is a link to some more documentation regarding the RoleManager:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1.roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_RoleManager_1_Roles

Comment: [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2079035.aspx?Identity+Get+Roles+and+display+in+DropDownList) Is it good way to use select? And can you give me hint how to "chain" user's selection to data in backend

Comment: @Allister it depends on what you need. If you need the user to select multiple roles then you would want to use a checkbox list as it is more intuitive then a multiple select. If you want the user to select a single role then you would use a select box.

Comment: Ok, I will use SelectListItem, because i want user to select one role. But how to add this selected data to backend, any hints?

Comment: @Allister once they click your Register button you will read the form values in your Action handler and then you will use the UserManager class to create the login and use AddToRoleAsync to add them to the selected role.